# Android CardView not displaying some TextView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat, android-cardview

[As u can see there is some text missing in some CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA9Hn.png) 
I am trying to simply make TextView appear inside a CardView.All I need to do is make texts appear inside the CardView.The CardView appear, but some CardView do not show any text  inside them.

**item_names.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
android:elevation="5dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberCount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numberCount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arabicName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/meaning"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/arabicName"
         android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_allah_names.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.islamiclearn.namesofallah.activity.AllahNamesActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/rcv"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

**AllahNamesActivity.java**

```
public class AllahNamesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<Names> list;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private AdView mAdView1;

/*
 Intent communicate b/w Android components like Activity,
    Service, Broadcast
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_allah_names);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");


    mAdView1 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view1);


    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    mAdView1.loadAd(adRequest);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcv);

    getNames();

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(AllahNamesActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("Position", position);
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("LIST", (ArrayList<Names>) list);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }));


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void getNames() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Names>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Names> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return fillArray();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Names> names) {
            super.onPostExecute(names);

            if (names != null && names.size() > 0) {
                list = names;

                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(AllahNamesActivity.this, 2));
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new NamesAdapter(list));
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

private List<Names> fillArray() {
    String[] arraCount = getResources().getStringArray(item_count);
    String[] arra = getResources().getStringArray(names);
    String[] arraArabic = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names_arabic);
    String[] arraMeaning = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.meaning);
    String[] music = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.music);


    List<Names> namesList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
        Names names = new Names();
        names.setCount(arraCount[i]);
        names.setName(arra[i]);
        names.setArabicName(arraArabic[i]);
        names.setMeaning(arraMeaning[i]);

        int resID = getId(music[i]);
        names.setResId(resID);
        namesList.add(names);

    }

    Items items = new Items();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    items.setArabicList(list);

    return namesList;
}

public int getId(String resName) {
    return getResources().getIdentifier(resName,
            "raw", getPackageName());
}
```

}

**arrays.xml**

```
<resources>
<string-array name="item_count">
    <item>"1"</item>
    <item>"2"</item>
    <item>"3"</item>
    <item>"4"</item>
    <item>"5"</item>
    <item>"6"</item>
    <item>"7"</item>
    <item>"8"</item>
    <item>"9"</item>
    <item>"10"</item>
    <item>"11"</item>
    <item>"12"</item>
    <item>"13"</item>
    <item>"14"</item>
    <item>"15"</item>
    <item>"16"</item>
    <item>"17"</item>
    <item>"18"</item>
    <item>"19"</item>
    <item>"20"</item>
    <item>"21"</item>
    <item>"22"</item>
    <item>"23"</item>
    <item>"24"</item>
    <item>"25"</item>
    <item>"26"</item>
    <item>"27"</item>
    <item>"28"</item>
    <item>"29"</item>
    <item>"30"</item>
    <item>"31"</item>
    <item>"32"</item>
    <item>"33"</item>
    <item>"34"</item>
    <item>"35"</item>
    <item>"36"</item>
    <item>"37"</item>
    <item>"38"</item>
    <item>"39"</item>
    <item>"40"</item>
    <item>"41"</item>
    <item>"42"</item>
    <item>"43"</item>
    <item>"44"</item>
    <item>"45"</item>
    <item>"46"</item>
    <item>"47"</item>
    <item>"48"</item>
    <item>"49"</item>
    <item>"50"</item>
    <item>"51"</item>
    <item>"52"</item>
    <item>"53"</item>
    <item>"54"</item>
    <item>"55"</item>
    <item>"56"</item>
    <item>"57"</item>
    <item>"58"</item>
    <item>"59"</item>
    <item>"60"</item>
    <item>"61"</item>
    <item>"62"</item>
    <item>"63"</item>
    <item>"64"</item>
    <item>"65"</item>
    <item>"66"</item>
    <item>"67"</item>
    <item>"68"</item>
    <item>"69"</item>
    <item>"70"</item>
    <item>"71"</item>
    <item>"72"</item>
    <item>"73"</item>
    <item>"74"</item>
    <item>"75"</item>
    <item>"76"</item>
    <item>"77"</item>
    <item>"78"</item>
    <item>"79"</item>
    <item>"80"</item>
    <item>"81"</item>
    <item>"82"</item>
    <item>"83"</item>
    <item>"84"</item>
    <item>"85"</item>
    <item>"86"</item>
    <item>"87"</item>
    <item>"88"</item>
    <item>"89"</item>
    <item>"90"</item>
    <item>"91"</item>
    <item>"92"</item>
    <item>"93"</item>
    <item>"94"</item>
    <item>"95"</item>
    <item>"96"</item>
    <item>"97"</item>
    <item>"98"</item>
    <item>"99"</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="names">
    <item>Ar-Rahman</item>
    <item>\'Ar-Rahim</item>
    <item>Al-Malik</item>
    <item> Al-Quddus</item>
    <item>As-Salam</item>
    <item>Al-Mu\'min</item>
    <item>Al-Muhaymin</item>
    <item>Al-Aziz</item>
    <item>Al-Jabbar</item>
    <item>Al-Mutakabbir</item>
    <item>Al-Khaliq</item>
    <item> Al-Bari\'</item>
    <item>Al-Musawwir</item>
    <item>Al-Ghaffar</item>
    <item>Al-Qahhar </item>
    <item>Al-Wahhab</item>
    <item>Ar-Razzaq</item>
    <item>Al-Fattah</item>
    <item>Al-\'Alim</item>
    <item>Al-Qabid</item>
    <item>Al-Basit</item>
    <item>Al-Khafid</item>
    <item>Ar-Rafi</item>
    <item>Al-Mu\'izz</item>
    <item>Al-Mudhill</item>
    <item>As-Sami</item>
    <item>Al-Basir</item>
    <item>Al-Hakam</item>
    <item>Al-\'Adl</item>
    <item>Al-Latif</item>
    <item>Al-Khabir</item>
    <item>Al-Halim</item>
    <item>Al-Azim</item>
    <item>Al-Ghafur</item>
    <item>Ash-Shakur</item>
    <item>Al-Ali</item>
    <item>Al-Kabir</item>
    <item>Al-Hafiz</item>
    <item>Al-Muqit</item>
    <item>Al-Hasib</item>
    <item>Al-Jalil</item>
    <item>Al-Karim</item>
    <item>Ar-Raqib</item>
    <item>Al-Mujib</item>
    <item>Al-Wasi</item>
    <item>Al-Hakim</item>
    <item>Al-Wadud</item>
    <item>Al-Majid</item>
    <item>Al-Ba\'ith</item>
    <item>Ash-Shahid</item>
    <item>Al-Haqq</item>
    <item>Al-Wakil</item>
    <item>Al-Qawiyy</item>
    <item>Al-Matin</item>
    <item>Al-Waliyy</item>
    <item>Al-Hamid</item>
    <item>Al-Muhsi</item>
    <item>Al-Mubdi\'</item>
    <item>Al-Mu\'id</item>
    <item>Al-Muhyi</item>
    <item>Al-Mumit</item>
    <item>Al-Hayy</item>
    <item>Al-Qayyum</item>
    <item>Al-Wajid</item>
    <item>Al-Majid</item>
    <item>Al-Wahid</item>
    <item>Al-Ahad</item>
    <item>As-Samad</item>
    <item>Al-Qadir</item>
    <item>Al-Muqtadir</item>
    <item>Al-Muqaddim</item>
    <item>Al-Mu\'akhkhir</item>
    <item>Al-Awwal</item>
    <item>Al-Akhir</item>
    <item>Az-Zahir</item>
    <item>Al-Batin</item>
    <item>Al-Wali</item>
    <item>Al-Muta\'ali</item>
    <item>Al-Barr</item>
    <item>At-Tawwab</item>
    <item>Al-Muntaqim</item>
    <item>Al-\'Afuww</item>
    <item>Ar-Ra\'uf</item>
    <item>Malik-al-Mulk</item>
    <item>Dhu-al-Jalal \n wa-al-Ikram</item>
    <item>Al-Muqsit</item>
    <item>Al-Jami\'</item>
    <item>Al-Ghani</item>
    <item>Al-Mughni</item>
    <item>Al-Mani\'</item>
    <item>Ad-Darr</item>
    <item>An-Nafi\'</item>
    <item>An-Nur</item>
    <item>Al-Hadi</item>
    <item>Al-Badi</item>
    <item>Al-Baqi</item>
    <item>Al-Warith</item>
    <item>Ar-Rashid</item>
    <item>As-Sabur</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="names_arabic">

    <item>الرحمن</item>
    <item >الرحيم</item>
    <item> الملك</item>
    <item> القدوس</item>
    <item>السلام</item>
    <item>المؤمن</item>
    <item >المهيمن</item>
    <item >العزيز</item>
    <item>الجبار</item>
    <item >المتكبر</item>
    <item >الخالق</item>
    <item >البارئ</item>
    <item >المصور</item>
    <item >الغفار</item>
    <item >القهار</item>
    <item >الوهاب</item>
    <item >الرزاق</item>
    <item >الفتاح</item>
    <item >العليم</item>
    <item >القابض</item>
    <item >الباسط</item>
    <item >الخافض</item>
    <item >الرافع</item>
    <item >المعز</item>
    <item >المذل</item>
    <item >السميع</item>
    <item >البصير</item>
    <item >الحكم</item>
    <item >العدل</item>
    <item >اللطيف</item>
    <item >الخبير</item>
    <item >الحليم</item>
    <item >العظيم</item>
    <item >الغفور</item>
    <item >الشكور</item>
    <item >العلى</item>
    <item >الكبير</item>
    <item >الحفيظ</item>
    <item >المقيت</item>
    <item >الحسيب</item>
    <item >الجليل</item>
    <item >الكريم</item>
    <item >الرقيب</item>
    <item >المجيب</item>
    <item >الواسع</item>
    <item >الحكيم</item>
    <item >الودود</item>
    <item >المجيد</item>
    <item >الباعث</item>
    <item >الشهيد</item>
    <item >الحق</item>
    <item >الوكيل</item>
    <item >القوى</item>
    <item >المتين</item>
    <item > الولى</item>
    <item >الحميد</item>
    <item >المحصى</item>
    <item >المبدئ</item>
    <item >المعيد</item>
    <item >المحيى</item>
    <item >المميت</item>
    <item >الحي</item>
    <item >القيوم</item>
    <item >الواجد</item>
    <item >الماجد</item>
    <item >الواحد</item>
    <item >الصمد</item>
    <item >الاحد</item>
    <item >القادر</item>
    <item >المقتدر</item>
    <item >المقدم</item>
    <item >المؤخر</item>
    <item >الأول</item>
    <item >الأخر</item>
    <item >الظاهر</item>
    <item >الباطن</item>
    <item >الوالي</item>
    <item >المتعالي</item>
    <item >البر</item>
    <item >التواب</item>
    <item >المنتقم</item>
    <item >العفو</item>
    <item >الرؤوف</item>
    <item >مالك الملك</item>
    <item >ذو الجلال و الإكرام</item>
    <item >المقسط</item>
    <item >الجامع</item>
    <item >الغنى</item>
    <item >المغنى</item>
    <item > المانع</item>
    <item > الضار</item>
    <item >النافع</item>
    <item > النور</item>
    <item >الهادي</item>
    <item >البديع</item>
    <item >الباقي</item>
    <item >الوارث</item>
    <item > الرشيد</item>
    <item > الصبور</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="meaning">
    <item >The All-Compassionate</item>
    <item >The All-Merciful</item>
    <item >The Absolute Ruler</item>
    <item >The Pure One</item>
    <item >The Source of Peace</item>
    <item >The Inspirer of Faith</item>
    <item >The Guardian</item>
    <item >The Victorious</item>
    <item >The Compeller</item>
    <item >The Greatest</item>
    <item >The Creator</item>
    <item >The Maker of Order</item>
    <item >The Shaper of Beauty</item>
    <item >The Forgiving</item>
    <item >The Subduer</item>
    <item >The Giver of All</item>
    <item >The Sustainer</item>
    <item >The Opener</item>
    <item >The Knower of All</item>
    <item >The Constrictor</item>
    <item >The Reliever</item>
    <item >The Abaser</item>
    <item >The Exalter</item>
    <item >The Bestower of Honors</item>
    <item >The Humiliator</item>
    <item >The Hearer of All</item>
    <item >The Seer of All</item>
    <item >The Judge</item>
    <item >The Just</item>
    <item >The Subtle One</item>
    <item >The All-Aware</item>
    <item >The Forbearing</item>
    <item >The Magnificent</item>
    <item >The Forgiver and Hider of Faults</item>
    <item >The Rewarder of Thankfulness</item>
    <item >The Highest</item>
    <item >The Greatest</item>
    <item >The Preserver</item>
    <item >The Nourisher</item>
    <item >The Accounter</item>
    <item >The Mighty</item>
    <item >The Generous</item>
    <item >The Watchful One</item>
    <item >The Responder to Prayer</item>
    <item >The All-Comprehending</item>
    <item >The Perfectly Wise</item>
    <item >The Loving One</item>
    <item >The Majestic One</item>
    <item >The Resurrector</item>
    <item >The Witness</item>
    <item >The Truth</item>
    <item >The Trustee</item>
    <item >The Possessor of All Strength</item>
    <item >The Forceful One</item>
    <item >The Governor</item>
    <item >The Praised One</item>
    <item >The Appraiser</item>
    <item >The Originator</item>
    <item >The Restorer</item>
    <item >The Giver of Life</item>
    <item >The Taker of Life</item>
    <item >The Ever Living One</item>
    <item >The Self-Existing One</item>
    <item >The Finder</item>
    <item >The Glorious</item>
    <item >The Unique, The Single</item>
    <item >The One, The Indivisible</item>
    <item >The Satisfier of All Needs</item>
    <item >The All Powerful</item>
    <item >The Creator of All Power</item>
    <item >The Expediter</item>
    <item >The Delayer</item>
    <item >The First</item>
    <item >The Last</item>
    <item >The Manifest One</item>
    <item >The Hidden One</item>
    <item >The Protecting Friend</item>
    <item >The Supreme One</item>
    <item >The Doer of Good</item>
    <item >The Guide to Repentance</item>
    <item >The Avenger</item>
    <item >The Forgiver</item>
    <item >The Clement</item>
    <item >The Owner of All</item>
    <item >The Lord of Majesty and Bounty</item>
    <item >The Equitable One</item>
    <item >The Gatherer</item>
    <item >The Rich One</item>
    <item >The Enricher</item>
    <item >The Preventer of Harm</item>
    <item >The Creator of The Harmful</item>
    <item >The Creator of Good</item>
    <item >The Light</item>
    <item >The Guide</item>
    <item >The Originator</item>
    <item >The Everlasting One</item>
    <item >The Inheritor of All</item>
    <item >The Righteous Teacher</item>
    <item >The Patient One  </item>

</string-array>
<string-array name="music">
    <item>    rahman</item>
    <item>   rahim      </item>
    <item> malik </item>
    <item>  quddus </item>
    <item> salam</item>
    <item> mumin </item>
    <item> muhaimin</item>
    <item> aziz</item>
    <item>  jabbar</item>
    <item> mutakabbir</item>
    <item>  khaliq</item>
    <item> bari</item>
    <item> musawwir</item>
    <item> ghaffar</item>
    <item>  qahhar</item>
    <item> wahhab</item>
    <item>  razzaq</item>
    <item> fattah</item>
    <item>  alim </item>
    <item> qabid </item>
    <item> basit</item>
    <item> khafid </item>
    <item> rafi </item>
    <item>  muizz </item>
    <item>  mudhill </item>
    <item> sami</item>
    <item>  basir</item>
    <item> hakam</item>
    <item> adl </item>
    <item> latif</item>
    <item> khabir</item>
    <item> halim</item>
    <item>  azim</item>
    <item>  ghafur</item>
    <item>shakur</item>
    <item>  ali</item>
    <item> kabir</item>
    <item>hafiz</item>
    <item>  muqit</item>
    <item> hasib</item>
    <item> jalil</item>
    <item>  karim</item>
    <item>  raqib</item>
    <item> mujib</item>
    <item> wasi</item>
    <item> hakim</item>
    <item>  wadud</item>
    <item>  majeed</item>
    <item>  baith</item>
    <item> shahid</item>
    <item> haqq</item>
    <item>  wakil</item>
    <item>  qawi</item>
    <item> matin</item>
    <item> wali</item>
    <item> hamid</item>
    <item> muhsi</item>
    <item>   mubdi</item>
    <item> muid</item>
    <item> muhyi</item>
    <item> mumit</item>
    <item>  hayy</item>
    <item> qayyum</item>
    <item> wajid</item>
    <item>  majeed</item>
    <item>   wahid</item>
    <item>   a</item>
    <item>    samad</item>
    <item>   qadir</item>
    <item>   muqtadir</item>
    <item>   muqaddim</item>
    <item>   muakhkhir2a</item>
    <item>  awwal</item>
    <item>   akhir</item>
    <item>  zahir</item>
    <item>  batin</item>
    <item>  wali</item>
    <item>   muta_ali</item>
    <item>    barr</item>
    <item>   tawwab</item>
    <item>   muntaqim</item>
    <item>  afuw</item>
    <item>   rauf</item>
    <item>   malik_ul_mulk</item>
    <item>   dhu_l_jalali_wal_ikram</item>
    <item>   muqsit</item>
    <item>   jami</item>
    <item>  ghaniy</item>
    <item>  mughni</item>
    <item>  mani</item>
    <item>  darr</item>
    <item>   nafi</item>
    <item>    nur</item>
    <item>  hadi</item>
    <item>    badi</item>
    <item>    baqi</item>
    <item>    warith</item>
    <item>rashid</item>
    <item>sabur</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is with your arrays, you need to debug to check. You can post your arrays.

Comment: try set yours textview layout_height with "wrap_content"